# Alarm manager which set only once after two minutes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have found many answers on alarmmanager which set repeated alarm but i want to set alarm which set alarm after 2 minutes after I click the button and it will be for only once, I do not want it to repeat.

Please help

Comment: ... and? what does it take to use `set()` instead of `setRepeating()`? Did you even search about the subject?

Comment: you can use handler to wait for 2 minutes or set alarm after 2 minutes and call intent service, that service set your one time alarm

Comment: I want to set alarm after 2 minutes of current time, and after that two minutes i want it executed so i can use it in broadcastreceiver

Comment: Use a timer, handler or countdowntimer if you only want it to be worked once.

Answer (score 1):

API < 19

Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Reference:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it'll be useful for you

```
    int milliseconds = 120000;


new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            yourMethod(); // this method will be called after 2 minutes 

        }
    },milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this will notify only once after 2 mins you can change it to seconds or hours also.

**JAVA**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2); //Minutes
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadCastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);    
alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

**KOTLIN**

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2)
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager?
val alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
alarmIntent.action = "FOO_ACTION"
alarmIntent.putExtra("alarm", "A")
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0)
alarmManager!!.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
```